# background-image won't display in CSS container

Tags: html, css

[Directory Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghbAF.png)I seem to be having problems with this container. Any text I put in will display but the background image will not. **I made a  tag with a class of my catimage** (category image).

```
/*css for catogories*/
.catimage {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(C:\server\media\site_pictures\tools.jpg);
}

/*html stuff*/
<div class="catimage"></div>
```

Comment: it's for sure a url problem

Comment: Is that what it is, Temani? I'm new to HTML/CSS so I don't know a lot.

Comment: you need to check the url of the image your are using, it seems incorrect

Comment: I added my directory info to the description but it all seems correct. @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url for the image needs to be relative to the file requesting it.

`background-image: url(./media/site_pictures/tools.jpg);`